# How to run a function in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, threadpool, qfuturewatcher

I'm making an emulator and I need to run the loop that executes instructions in another thread (preferably with QtConcurrent). I am currently doing it like this

```cpp
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentRun>
#include <QThread>
QFutureWatcher<void> futureWatcher;
bool running = false;

void MainWindow::startExecution() {
    running = true;
    futureWatcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::run([this]() {
        while(running){
            qDebug() << "Physical Thread ID: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
            QThread::msleep(100);
            //execute instructions
        }
    }));
}

void MainWindow::stopExecution()
{
    running = false;
    futureWatcher.waitForFinished();
}
```

The issue is every time that `futureWatcher` is run, it starts running in another thread. And after 8 runs (or how many threads my CPU has) the `futureWatcher` won't run anymore. I proved this by doing this:

```cpp
qDebug() << "Physical Thread ID: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
```

This is called as soon as the `futureWatcher` starts.

Snippet of the output:

```
called from Physical Thread ID:  0x2768
Physical Thread ID:  0x8c4
called from Physical Thread ID:  0x2768
Physical Thread ID:  0x1414
called from Physical Thread ID:  0x2768
Physical Thread ID:  0x20d0
called from Physical Thread ID:  0x2768
Physical Thread ID:  0x2768
called from Physical Thread ID:  0x2768
Physical Thread ID:  0x2768
called from Physical Thread ID:  0x2768
Physical Thread ID:  0x2768
```

As soon as the threads are the same, it no longer behaves correctly and the loop doesn't run when `setFuture` is called, but it is actually run when `futureWatcher.waitForFinished();` is called in `stopExecution()`.

I only need 2 threads. One is the main thread and the other for the execution. Is there a way to always run the future watcher in the same second thread? What other solutions can I use?

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks. This is my first proper post here, is it better now?

Comment: You have a data race on `running` and therefore your program's behavior is undefined.  Have you tried using a `std::atomic<bool>` instead?

Comment: No, it's not better, I'm afraid. Which part of "can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue" was unclear? Do you think I can cut/paste the above, into an empty file, and be able to compile it and see your issue? Of course not.

Answer (score 0):

I found an error. In the function that actually executes instructions there is one specific condition where that function calls `stopExecution`. I believe because that is called from the same thread that the `futureWatcher` is running, when `futureWatcher.waitForFinished();` is called, the next time `futureWatcher.setFuture` is called it is started on another thread. This assumption is based on testing the code with and without the condition that calls `stopExecution`.
I solved the issue by replacing every `stopExecution` call from inside the futureWatcher with `running = false;`. Now the code works as intended.
The previous solution with thread pools is unnecessary.

Answer (score -3):

The problem you are encountering is that `QtConcurrent::run` by default uses the global `QThreadPool`, which has a limited number of threads (usually as many as the number of CPU cores). Once all threads are in use, additional calls to `QtConcurrent::run` will queue the tasks until a thread becomes available.

In your case, because `running` is not turned `false` before calling `waitForFinished()`, the threads may not be properly released back to the pool. This is why after several runs, you no longer have any threads available to run new tasks.

If you want to ensure that you always have a thread available for your emulator's execution loop, you could create your own `QThreadPool` with a single thread and use that for your concurrent tasks.

Here's a rough example of how you could modify your code:

```cpp
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QtConcurrentRun>

QThreadPool executionPool;
QFutureWatcher<void> futureWatcher;
bool running = false;

void MainWindow::startExecution() {
    running = true;
    executionPool.setMaxThreadCount(1); // Ensure only one thread is in this pool

    // Pass the custom thread pool to QtConcurrent::run
    futureWatcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(&executionPool, [this]() {
        while(running){
            qDebug() << "Physical Thread ID: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
            QThread::msleep(100);
            //execute instructions
        }
    }));
}

void MainWindow::stopExecution() {
    running = false;
    futureWatcher.waitForFinished(); // This will now properly wait for the task to finish
}

// In your destructor, make sure to shutdown the thread pool
MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    executionPool.waitForDone(); // Wait for all tasks to finish
}
```

With this setup, you're controlling the thread pool directly and ensuring that only one thread will be used for your task, separate from the global thread pool. This should prevent the exhaustion of threads in the global pool.

Remember to handle thread safety when accessing and modifying shared resources between the main thread and the execution thread. If `running` is shared, it should at least be an atomic variable to prevent race conditions.

Finally, make sure to properly clean up the thread pool when your application is closing to prevent any threads from continuing to run in the background.

Resource: ChatGPT-4

Comment: The issue is still here. I am now using an atomic bool. Once again the execution thread keeps changing and when it reaches the same thread as the main thread. '.setFuture' does not run and '.waitForFinished' runs the code instead